# Is there a better way to stack and check results?

Tags: c#

See below method:

```
    public ApplicationStatus GetDecision(string applicationGuid)
    {
        try
        {
            var loanDecision = LoanRepository.GetLoanDecisionData(applicationGuid);

            if (loanDecision.ApplicationStatus != ApplicationStatus.OK)
            {
                return loanDecision.ApplicationStatus;
            }

            loanDecision = GetCreditBureauInfoForApplication(loanDecision);

            if (loanDecision.ApplicationStatus != ApplicationStatus.OK)
            {
                return loanDecision.ApplicationStatus;
            }

            loanDecision = GetCreditScore(loanDecision); //GetVantage - Using more generic name

            if (loanDecision.ApplicationStatus != ApplicationStatus.OK)
            {
                return loanDecision.ApplicationStatus;
            }


            return loanDecision.ApplicationStatus;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, $"GetDecisionFailed for ApplicationGuid: {applicationGuid}", "GetDecision");
            return ApplicationStatus.GeneralFailure;
        }
    }
```

I hate this - I actually have a few more lines that need to be added to each of the return statements.  I also have quite a few more methods not shown here -(Almost 10 total now - more potentially down the road.) I feel like its a total hack.  Does anyone have any suggestions on a better way to write this?

Comment: Chain of responsibility pattern: https://www.dofactory.com/net/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern

Comment: Is there a reason why your methods must run synchronously, in a given order?

Comment: What is it that you hate about this? The dependency between the `Get*` functions? The list if `If` constructs that you have to write?

Comment: also would be nice if you can tell how the `ApplicationStatus` enum looks like and if contains fields which tell about the failure of a given method:`GetCreditScore` or `GetCreditBureauInfoForApplication` etc.

Comment: GoldenAge - For some of them yes - the order is important.

Comment: What happens is that if one of methods fails (GetCreditScore, etc) a event log entry is written and the status of DecisionFailure is returned - (I did not want a ton of values - and since I write to the event log - I see no need for more values) If a status of DecisionFailure is returned at any point in the process the process needs to end ASAP and return with that status.  It is a somewhat linear decision process  - part of a very quick and dirty decision engine.